# Change colors sphinx_rtd_theme python docs

Tags: python, themes, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

In my conf.py I use the following to make docs with Sphinx and use a custom theme;

```
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"

 

html_static_path = ["_static"]

 

html_css_files = [

    'theme.css',

]
```

Within my theme.css file in the static folder I use the following;

```
:root {
    --sd-color-primary: #212529;
    --sd-color-primary-highlight: #212529;
    --sd-color-primary-text: #212529;
}
```

The docs still default to using the standard Blue.
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using sphinx-design? Your CSS variables come from that extension: https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/css_variables.html

Comment: I'm using the rtd_theme - same variables though.
https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-theme/css_variables.html

Comment: Unless you are actually using sphinx-design, the variables won't have any effect as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is the docs for the site
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html
Then I went to sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-theme/css_variables.html to see the options available.

Comment: Those options are available if you use the sphinx-design extension. They are not generic variables for styling any Sphinx output.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48540008/407651

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`add_css_file()`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_css_file) method instead.

In `conf.py` add the following:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file("theme.css")
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that way previously